# Grails 2.5.1 to grails 3.3.11 Upgrade Enum Type Response Issue

Tags: gradle, grails, enums, grails-orm

After upgrading from grails 2.5.1 to grails 3.3.11 , domain with enum type are rendering two different responses in the same api call.

Following are the responses from the same api call which switches periodically from one to another :

Response 1 :

```
"book": {
  "declaringClass": "com.test.book",
  "key": "MATH",
  "value": "‘Math’"
},
```

Response 2 :

```
"book": {
  "enumType": "com.test.book",
  "name": "MATH"
}
```

We should only get the following response :

```
"book": {
  "enumType": "com.test.book",
  "name": "MATH"
}
```

Domain Example :

```
package com.test

class Domain {
  Book book
}

enum Book  {
  MATH(‘Math’)
  
  final String value
  Book(String value)
  {
    this.value = value
  }

  String toString() { value }
  String getKey() { name() }
}
```

Gorm Version Used : 6.1.12.RELEASE

Dependency Used :

```
dependencies {
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.15.1"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17'
compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.52'
compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9'
compile group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.9.1'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:aws-sdk-kinesis:2.2.12'
compile 'com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.8.5'
compile "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.11.198"
compile 'agorapulse.libs:groovy-aws-sdk-util:1.1', {
exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
compile 'org.json:json:20190722'
compile "org.grails.plugins:asynchronous-mail:2.0.2"
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'rest-client-builder', version: '2.1.1'
compile "org.grails.plugins:jasypt-encryption:2.0.1"
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'scaffolding', version: '2.1.2'
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'asset-pipeline', version: '1.9.9'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:3.0.6'
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.8"
compile "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:8.0.22"
runtime group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'database-migration', version: '1.4.0'
testCompile "org.grails:grails-test-mixins:3.3.0"
implementation 'org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:3.3.3'
}
```

Comment: "Following are the responses from the same api call which switches periodically from one to another" - If you can reproduce that in an app that you can share, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will investigate.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What API call?  Can you show the controller/action you're hitting to get those results?